# Cannot load assembly

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, build, wpf-controls

I am baffled.  I have a WPF solution in which I have split out my various views into separate projects.  I also have a project for my custom controls.  Finally, my application is in another project, set as the default project.

My main window and one of my other views both use controls in the custom control project.  All of my projects build successfully except for the second view that uses a custom control.

I've been unable to duplicate this in an example app, but I'll do my best to illustrate here.

```
MySolution
    MyApp.csproj
       References
           MyMainWindow
           MySecondWindow
           MyThirdWindow
           MyViewModels
           [std WPF references]
       App.xaml
           App.xaml.cs
    MyMainWindow.csproj
       References
           MyControls
           [std WPF references]
       MainWindow.xaml
           MainWindow.xaml.cs
    MySecondWindow.csproj
       References
           [std WPF references]
       SecondWindow.xaml
           SecondWindow.xaml.cs
    MyThirdWindow.csproj
       References
           MyControls
           [std WPF references]
       ThirdWindow.xaml
           ThirdWindow.xaml.cs
    MyControls
       References
           [std WPF references]
       ControlForMainWindow.xaml
           ControlForMainWindow.xaml.cs
       ControlForThirdWindow.xaml
           ControlForThirdWindow.xaml.cs
```

In this (very crude) example, the MyMainWindow project and MyThirdWindow project are reference identical.  Every project except for MyThirdWindow builds successfully.  The error that I get is:

```
Could not load file or assembly '[MyControls]' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Does anyone know why one project would build when a seemingly identical project would fail?

**Edit 1:**

If I remove ControlForThirdWindow (and the namespace declaration) from MyThirdWindow (but leave the project reference), the entire solution builds and the app runs, even though MyMainWindow still uses ControlForMainWindow.  I have verified that the namespace declaration is correct (I copied it from MyMainWindow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been working on a task to move all of my windows to separate projects.  For each window, this required several steps:

- Create a new project
- Copy the window code to the new project
- Update the namespace in the copy
- Remove the window code from the application project
- Add a reference (and `using` statements) to the new project in the application project
- If necessary add references to dependencies in the new project
- Update the target framework

Apparently the target framework on MyControls was set to .NET Framework 4, and MyThirdWindow was set to .NET Framework 4 *Client Profile*.  I had set it on all of my other window projects and just missed this one.

Solution builds fine now.